# How to see heap performance while runing java webapplication?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I tried with Runtime.totalMemory()
I given one long value, I did not understand is it in mb or gb etc and I want how much heap size occupied with my application.

Could you please tell me any methods are there to see occupied memory and performance of heap while running application.

Comment: RTFM - it tells you what the unit is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have java installed in your machine, Go to the **run** and type **jconsole** and enter. 
You will see that a window is coming, it will prompt you to connect. Connect it with your running web application and then you will get VM Summary, Heap, Threads any many more relevant information.

Comment: One more small doubt, I testing in two different systems, while going to jconsole i got 2 options to select in one system but in another I got only below first option. In both systems have jdk 1.7
1) sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole 22208
2) org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 19124
What I need to select

Comment: But in another system I did not get that second option there I have only one option (sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole) what to do

Comment: In the other system your web application is running or not? If its running it will appear in the jconsole along with the PID(Process Id)

Comment: Yes application is running but not comming that second option, Ok I will try myself. Any way thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Refer http://viralpatel.net/blogs/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime/

You simply need to define the units and divide the no.